# Select row based on another row having same id in same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table view T like:

```
id | C1   | C2  |
---+------+-----+
1  | pat  | 190 |
1  | pat1 | 191 |
1  | A5   | 302 |
2  | pet  | 190 |
2  | pet1 | 191 |
2  | A5   | 302 |
3  | pit  | 190 |
3  | pit1 | 191 |
3  | A6   | 302 |
```

Would like to get:

```
id | C1   | C2  |
---+------+-----+
1  | pat  | 190 |
2  | pet  | 190 |
```

In other words, return id where C2 = 190 where same id elsewhere in table is A5.

Have tried several LEFT JOIN approaches but haven't gotten anywhere. Please help. Thanx.

Comment: You really should avoid duplicate values for "id", as at least when I see an id column I assume that that is the primary key

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, this is on a View.

Comment: That makes more sense. Well you could easily do this with an inner join, left join as you've found out won't work

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot use indexes, making them (to my mind) practically useless.

Comment: I know they don't use indexes. Whatever answer I get will try it on main tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where c2 = 190
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename where id = t.id and c1 = 'A5'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4BcEgUJ9RLDs2nbkii4nmw/0).
Results:

```
| id  | C1  | C2  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | pat | 190 |
| 2   | pet | 190 |
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and fast on a view with over 50k rows and over 80 fields. Thanx.

Comment: EXISTS is usually the most efficient way in such cases.

Comment: By the way, as an aside, how would you go about adding an additional condition, say 'where C3=1? Should it be place in the main body or inside the exists clause?

Comment: Depends on the logic of the condition: if it is something like the case of c1 = 'A5' then put it inside EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to check if a row with `c1 = 'A5'` exists for an ID.

```
SELECT *
       FROM t t1
       WHERE t1.c2 = 190
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM t t2
                                WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                                      AND t2.c1 = 'A5');
```